# Why const char* is not working with stringstream and read_json of boost?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am trying to pass a character pointer to function which will read_json using the string internally. But after coming out of the function, the pointer's content is getting changed. Below is the code.

```
string tempstr;
void someFunc()
{
    const char *ptr = getDiagnosticGroupValue("Device.ManagementServer");
    printf("string : %s\n", getParameterValue(ptr, "URL"));
    printf("string : %s\n", getParameterValue(ptr, "Username"));
}
const char* getParameterValue(const char *jsonstring, const char* param)
{
    return getString(jsonstring, param);
}
const char* getString(const char *jsonstring, const char* param)
{
    stringstream jsonstringstream;
    jsonstringstream << jsonstring;

    string paramstr(param);

    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json(jsonstringstream, pt);
        tempstr = pt.get<string>(paramstr);
        return tempstr.c_str();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        jsonstringstream.clear();
        jsonstringstream.str("");
        cout << "Node Doesn't exist" << endl;
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

For the first node (URL), it is returning correct value and I am able to print the string in someFunc(). But ptr content is getting modified (and it is no longer json format string). So the second time, when getParameterValue() is called, read_json is throwing exception saying not json format. I was wondering why the ptr contents are getting changed even though I declared as const char* ptr. Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue.

I confirmed the problem is not with temporary object. I modified the code by creating global string and returning char * from global string. But I am facing the same problem. One more thing is when getParameterValue() is called first time, I put the print statement after read_json() to check the value of ptr, and ptr is already corrupted by that time.

getDiagnosticGrouapValue() is implementation is as below.

```
const char* getDiagnosticGroupValue(const char* group)
{
    VZUAL& vzual = VZUAL::getInstance();

    string groupStr(group, group + strlen(group));
    return vzual.Diagnostics.getGroupValue(groupStr).c_str();
}

const string PlatformDiagnostics::getGroupValue(const string& _groupName_, const string& DUMMY)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptRead;
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptWrite;
    string path = _groupName_ + ".";
    stringstream ss;

    try {
        boost::property_tree::read_json(Resource::diagnosticsFile.c_str(), ptRead);
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error &je) {
        return Resource::defaultValue;
    }

    try {
        BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, ptRead.get_child(path))
        ptWrite.put(v.first.data(), v.second.data());
    }
    catch (...) {
    return Resource::defaultValue;
    }

    boost::property_tree::write_json(ss, ptWrite);
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag this question with [tag:c].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning pointer to string that is created on stack, inside getString function. This is undefined behaviour.

from your code, all the variables:

```
string paramstr(param);
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::read_json(jsonstringstream, pt);  
return (pt.get<string>(paramstr)).c_str();
```

indicate that this string is not created statically or globally.

If you are returning a pointer to some part of the jsonstring, ten maybe you should find this string inside jsonstring and return pointer to it. The problem is that it will not be null terminated (so you would need to return also lenght).

Other solution is to provide to getString a char array that will be returned from getString. But you must make sure its large enought, and incase it is too small then return NULL, so that the client code can provide larger buffer.

Comment: I confirmed the problem is not with temporary object. I modified the code by creating global string and returning char * from global string. But I am facing the same problem. One more thing is when getParameterValue() is called first time, I put the print statement after read_json() to check the value of ptr, and ptr is already corrupted by that time.

Comment: @kadina It's const char * so its hard to believe it gets modified, also you put it inside of stringstream, which surely is not changing it. Maybe there is no `Username` in this json? `problem is not with temporary object` - that is not true, you just have more than one problem:-) Your current solution with global variable is OK until you try to use your function from multiple threads, or try to store returned value somewhere.

Comment: Username is present in the json string. I removed the call to getString() with parameter "Username" and instead I just printed ptr after getString() in someFunc() and it is printing the corrupted string.

Comment: And I am running out of ideas now. I am still unsure how to debug this problem and how const char* ptr is getting modified.

Comment: Can you add your getDiagnosticGroupValue implementation?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I trapped in a meeting. I posted the implmentation.

Comment: @kadina as I suspected, your getDiagnosticGroupValue implementation suffers from the exact same problem, it returns temporary variable. Why it works the first time? - because its undefined behaviour. So the quick fix for you is with the global variable as You did previously.